# Output form data into a single line

Tags: php, forms, line-breaks

I have a form which sends data to a text file, but I'm trying to keep all data sent in the first line of that text file, and replacing would-be breaks with the br tags inside the text file itself.  Sorry if there's a really easy solution, but I've been searching and testing for over an hour now >_< (php newbie)

Edit: Yeah here's the general gist of what I currently have.  I'm using variables for it.
I have a form with one of the inputs named content that sends data to a submit.php.
In submit.php...

```
$content = $_POST['content'];
```

and that sends the following to a text file

```
$data = "$content";

$fh = fopen("file.txt", "a");
fwrite($fh, $data);
```

Comment: why you need to do that? what if you do json_encode of the data?

Comment: Json is probably a better solution too fyi

Comment: can you show us what you have so far

Comment: Well, I'm pulling only the first line to display in the main page, and then the rest of the lines are the comments which are displayed in the full page.  I also need each comment on their own line because I made a function to count how many lines there are to reflect how many comments there are.  Yeah I could use MySQL instead of forms, but my host only gave 2 databases, which I used up already lol.  And yeah, I'mma go look up json_encode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the php function `nl2br()` ([php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php)). It does exactly what you need, by going through the string you give it and replacing new lines (`\n`s and `\r`s) with `<br/>` tags.

Apparently `nl2br` doesn't remove the actual breaks, and only adds the br tags, so try this function:

```
function oneLiner ($str)
{
    $str = nl2br($str);
    $str = str_replace(array("\n","\r"), '', $str);
    return $str;
}
```

Comment: I already tried that, but I need to keep everything on the first line.  When I used nlbr it added br tags, it still created the line space in the text file.  But, I guess there's a good chance I somehow messed that up too and it IS supposed to remove all breaks in the text file.

Comment: hm, I guess you could run that, and then just remove the line spaces manually, one sec,

Comment: Try the above function instead

Comment: trying; currently trying to figure out where to put it. Might take another few minutes

Comment: instead of using the nl2br, call the function above